# How to Host Silverlight App in IIS

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm using Silverlight 4.0 and I need to know the process to deploy a Silverlight Application in IIS and requirements to host silverlight application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little guide: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/

Comment: am using iis 7.0 and i want to access it from everywhere, am able to browse in my ie but if i go for another pc it is not working. Do i need premium version of iis or not required

Comment: Have you chacked the firewall?

Answer (score -2):

this should help you get started [LINK1](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/) [LINK2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2008/03/18/configuring-a-web-server-to-host-silverlight-content.aspx)

Comment: am using tataphoton, can i get it using internet in another pc by entering the ipaddress

Comment: you should be able to access it with the right IP address port number combination....